# Monotouch Three20 app launcher or bindings

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, three20

From what I've read about [btouch](http://code.google.com/p/btouch-library/); the bindings are not complete for three20.

Is there a project that provides either bindings for the Three20 app launcher or a pure MonoTouch implementation of a launcher UI element?

http://three20.info/showcase/launcher

[image]

Comment: Looks like there's at least a good start on them here: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Three20

Comment: Here are some bindings for Nimbus. Use it instead. https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.Nimbus

Answer (score 2):

There are two different bindings that I have seen. I personally have used the one from GitHub to use the launcher in a MonoTouch app and it is working fine. I haven't used the one from Google Code.

[Three20 Binding @ Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/btouch-library/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Three20)

[Three20 Binding @ GitHub](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Three20/binding)

Comment: Definitely use the GitHub code.  It includes the new `LinkWith` assembly attributes, which make it so much easier to compile/link your monotouch probjects

Answer (score 1):

Nimbus is the new open-source project from Jeff Verkoey (who brought you Three20) that is trying to minimize Three20's sprawling, lengthy build process while providing extensive documentation and feature parity. There's an awesome launcher demo available as part of the project. I don't know about bindings or MonoTouch, but it's a very nice and elegant way to present a launcher. Try it out if possible.

Once you've used Nimbus, the only reason to go back to Three20 is for a feature it doesn't yet support. It's incredibly fast to build and use in general. I highly recommend it. It's also being extensively developed, so that's a drawback if the launcher is one such item.

The link is https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus. Hope this helped!

Comment: And here are the bindings for this wonderful library (work in progress)! https://github.com/theonlylawislove/MonoTouch.Nimbus